# How to point django form to pk?

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to make a form that is dynamically selected by a DetailView object.

I want to click the DetailView link and be taken to a form whose primary key is the same as the primary key from my detail view. When I attempt to do this I get an error. How can I do this? Is their a prebuilt library that will assist me?

My Model:

'''

```
 class MemberStudent(models.Model):
    instructor = models.ForeignKey(Teachers, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Doe")
    age = models.IntegerField(default=99)


 def __str__(self):
      return self.name

 def get_absolute_url(self):
      return reverse('student_detail', args=[str(self.id)])

class BehaviorGrade(models.Model):
   SEVERITY = [
    ('Bad','Bad Behavior'),
    ('Good','Good Behavior'),
    ('Danger','Dangerous'),
]

LETTER_GRADE = [
    ('A','A'),
    ('B','B'),
    ('F','F'),
]

studentName = models.ForeignKey(MemberStudent,      on_delete=models.CASCADE) #need a link to student name
eventGrade = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=LETTER_GRADE)
eventSeverity = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=SEVERITY)
eventTitle = models.CharField(max_length=15)
eventDescription = models.TextField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.eventTitle
```

'''

My Views:

'''

```
class StudentDetailView(FormMixin,DetailView):
   model = MemberStudent
   template_name = 'student_detail.html'
   form_class = BehaviorForm

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('student_detail', kwargs={'pk':self.object.pk})



def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
   
    self.object = self.get_object()
    form = self.get_form()
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return self.form_valid(form)
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form)

def form_valid(self, form):
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

'''

my forms.py:
'''

```
class BehaviorForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = BehaviorGrade
    fields = ['eventGrade',
              'eventSeverity','eventTitle',
              'eventDescription']
```

'''

my url:

'''

```
 path('students/<int:pk>', StudentDetailView.as_view(), name='student_detail'),
```

'''

my htmltemplate(its a detailview with a form below on the same page):
'''

```
 {{ object.id }}
 {{ object.name }}
 {{ object.age }}

 {{ object.instructor }}



  <form action="{% url 'student_detail' object.id %}" method="POST">
  {{ form }}
  {% csrf_token %}
<input type="submit" value="REVIEW">

  </form>
```

'''

error message when form submitted:

"IntegrityError at /student/students/1

NOT NULL constraint failed: Students_behaviorgrade.studentName_id"

The form also is sent without the PK I have requested in my form code.

the django error log shows the PK is never sent
here is the log message on a test of dummy data:

params  [None, 'A', 'Bad', 'asdf', 'asdf']

Comment: What's the error saying ?

Comment: "IntegrityError at /student/students/1

NOT NULL constraint failed: Students_behaviorgrade.studentName_id"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have to manually set the member student id on the behavior garde.

You can do it like this in the `post` function of your view :

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    form = self.get_form()
    if form.is_valid():
        behavior_grade = form.save(commit=False)
        behavior_grade.studentName = self.object
        return self.form_valid(form)
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form)
```

You can also take a look at [this method](http://dashdrum.com/blog/2012/01/a-better-way-dont/) to use the `form_valid` function to do it :

> ```
> ## Include the instance object before saving
> def form_valid(self, form):
>     form.instance.studentName = self.object
>     return super().form_valid(form)
> ```

Comment: Thank you @ Benbb96 for these solutions. I read the Django docs but could not find this type of logic you provided.  Does this method you are using have a name?  Do you have a good webresource to learn intresting Django techniques that you can share with me?

Comment: Did you managed to make it worked with my answer ?

Usually, the Django docs are complete enough but if I have a specific issue, I just google it and StackOverflow is often the first result. But I also found a lot of ressources on this blog : https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/

Comment: No, it still doesnt work. It seems my question is how do I pass a parameter to the form from the backend. wehn testing the the primary key is not being passed inside of the form  the params in my test show as "params [None, 'A', 'Bad', 'asdf', 'asdf']"

Comment: I got it to work. I called the object key in my save method. Thanks I could not have figured this out without the methods you shared.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to to call the primary key in the model method. Then to save to the correct model object I called .pk on my object. I'm cannot elegantly explain this solution however upon testing several different scenarios it works.

'''

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    form = self.get_form()
    if form.is_valid():
        behavior_grade = form.save(commit=False)
        behavior_grade.studentName = self.object #passes unamed form field
        behavior_grade.studentName.pk = form.save(commit=True) #calls key 
        return self.form_valid(form)
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form)
```

'''